# Array of 2D arrays C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to know if it is possible to create an array that is composed of 2D arrays.

I have a function that modifies the content of a 2D array, in my program this function is called 2035 times. And each time the result is saved in the same 2D array. So of course I can have access to only the 2035 update of the 2D array.

- Is it possible to have an array of 2D arrays?
- Is there a way to save each 2D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of an array is called a "2D array", and it looks like this:

```
int arr[100][500];
```

i.e. an array containing 100 arrays, each of length 500.

---

An array of a 2D array is called a "3D array", and it looks like this:

```
int arr[2035][100][100]
```

i.e. an array containing 2035 2D arrays, each of dimension 100x100.

Comment: Thanks! I guess starting to learn c by trying to implement AES makes you dumb ^^

Comment: @MFadil, Nothing like that. But you should start from simpler problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
int** arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*5);
int a;
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++){
    arr[a] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
}
arr[3][1] = 2;
```

This way to make a dinamic vector in C in easy mode... But this isn't organized.

:)